# Is there a perl 5.005 core module that would convert epoch seconds to a datetime string?

Tags: perl, datetime, epoch

Is there a perl core module in 5.005 that would convert epoch seconds to printable datetime?

Our system has DateTime.pm, but the script in need of the functionality is still on Perl 5.005 and not feasible to upgrade it to 5.6+ (don't ask. Just Cant Be Done for non-technical reasons). DateTime.pm - at least the version we have - requires 5.6.

Therefore I need one of the following:

- Ideally, a module that is in Perl 5.005 core that would convert epoch seconds to date/time string. Preferably in YY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss format but not required.
- Failing that, a 5.005-compatible non-XS module that would convert epoch seconds to date/time string. Preferably in YY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss format but not required.

  Strong preference for a module that would have had this functionality on CPAN when Perl 5.005 was released (that way it is plausible it'd be in company's existing set of CPAN modules)

Comment: "don't ask. Just Cant Be Done for non-technical reasons" Nonsense!  http://search.cpan.org/~gugod/App-perlbrew-0.33/lib/App/perlbrew.pm

Comment: @Jack - which part of "non-technical" applies to a technical solution you proposed? Some developers exist in large corporate environments with those things called "policies".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) the [POSIX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/POSIX) module is available. So you can use the `strftime` function. This is what I use all the time in 5.8.8

```
use POSIX();
my $time_t = 1234567890;
my $txt = POSIX::strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %T", localtime($time_t) );
print "$txt\n";
```

Gives

```
2009-02-14 10:31:30
```

Answer (score 5):

See the core routines [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) and [`gmtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime.html) (also [`time`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html)).

IMHO, it's usually easier to write a small subroutine to do this sort of formatting than to introduce a new dependency. For example:

```
sub epoch_to_datetime {
  my $time = shift(@_) || time();
  my ($s, $m, $h, $md, $mo, $yr) = localtime($time);
  my $date = join("/",
      sprintf("%02d", $yr % 100),
      sprintf("%02d", $mo + 1),
      sprintf("%02d", $md));
  my $time = join(":",
      sprintf("%02d", $h),
      sprintf("%02d", $m),
      sprintf("%02d", $s));
  return "$date $time";
}

print epoch_to_datetime(time()) . "\n";
# 11/11/09 08:06:10
```

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX::strftime solution is the most flexible one. But if you're not very choosy about the exact format, then you can use `localtime` (or `gmtime`) in scalar context to get a human-readable datetime string from epoch seconds.

```
$ perl -le'print scalar localtime 1000000000'
Sun Sep  9 02:46:40 2001
```